# How to get callback on deselect marker from google maps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

i tried to get a callback on action like `deselect` Marker. but in properties the Marker, i found only `onTap` callback. how i can resolve this problem? my init of the marker for exaample

```
  Marker createMarkerFromPlace(Place place, void Function(String uid) onTap) {
    return Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(place.uuid),
        draggable: false,
        visible: true,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: place.name,
          snippet: place.vicinity
        ),
        position: LatLng(
          place.geometry.location.lat,
          place.geometry.location.lng
        ),
        onTap: (){ onTap(place.uuid); }
    );
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying  to execute something after deselecting a marker?

Comment: yep! like event in apple map. now I did it by the event `onTap` on the `GoogleMap` widget. but I thinking it is not a good way